# Looking for geojson data host?

Tags: postgresql, geojson, mysql, google

I want to use geojson data in google map application like this ([enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/combining-data)).

The geojson data (see link [enter link description here](https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/states.js)) is what I am looking for.

Do I need a (online) database server to run it?

Does mySQL or PostgreSQL work?

I know I can add geojson data (text) directly to the code, but it make the loading slow. Somebody mentioned MongoDB could handle geojson data, but I never used it.

Comment: Is the data sensitive or private? If no, have you considered hosting for free on GitHub?

Comment: Just regular spatial data. I never used GitHub before. I am reading GitHub now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is not sensitive or private in nature and does not violate any organizational data policies it is possible to host GeoJSON on GitHub. [See documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/mapping-geojson-files-on-github/). Simply commit the file as you would normally using a `.geojson` extension then use the URL for the GeoJSON in your application. eg. `https://github.com/<username>/<project>/blob/master/<file>.geojson`

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Thanks@danagerous. GitHub worked great. My original data was shapefile. QGIS was used to convert shapefile into geojson (which needs coordinates in decimal degrees), which was eventually moved to GitHub. Loading geojson data from GitHub was perfect for google map application.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. I will make my comment an answer and if you would kindly accept the answer that would be appreciated.